# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-viewpager, android-tabs

I'm trying to implement sliding tab layout using android material design. But it gives me `NullPointerException`. Here is my code so far:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private ViewPager pager;
    private SlidingTabLayout nLayout;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        NavigationDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer_fragment);
        drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.navigation_drawer_fragment, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
        pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        pager.setAdapter(new MyPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager()));

        nLayout = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        nLayout.setViewPager(pager);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        if (id == R.id.navigate) {
            startActivity(new Intent(this, SubActivity.class));

        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    class MyPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        String tabs[];

        public MyPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
            tabs = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            MyFragment myFragment = MyFragment.getInstance(position);
            return myFragment;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return tabs[position];
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }
    }

    public static class MyFragment extends Fragment {
        private TextView textView;

        public static MyFragment getInstance(int position) {
            MyFragment myFragment = new MyFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("position", position);
            myFragment.setArguments(args);
            return myFragment;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my, container, false);
            textView = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.position);
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            if (bundle != null) {
                textView.setText("The page selected is " + bundle.getInt("position"));
            }
            return layout;
        }
    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="carsaleapp.shanaka.com.carsaleapp.MainActivity">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/app_bar" />

    <app.shanaka.tabs.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />


</LinearLayout>
```

This is the error I got after run my application:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{carsaleapp.shanaka.com.carsaleapp/carsaleapp.shanaka.com.carsaleapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter)' on a null object reference
            at carsaleapp.shanaka.com.carsaleapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:42)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2360)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1278)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5221)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
```

They keep on saying that the `pager` object is null. But for me I have set it correctly.

```
pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have your view pager in `activity_main.xml` while your layout for activity is 
        `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_appbar)`. You do not have view pager in `activity_main_appbar.xml`.

`findViewById` looks for a view in the current view hierarchy. I guess it should be `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` but do check what views you have in included layout `app_bar.xml`

Comment: Of course it is. Dont know how I did miss that point. anyway It works perfectly after `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` Thank you.

Comment: i had the same error but because of i missed pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
 part

Answer (score 2):

It May be you pass an wrong id of viewPager.Please Check your id from XML File

Comment: This does not provide any value to the question.

Comment: Solved my issue. Thanks.